# Cannot create ActiveX component on SAP.Functions

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, saprfc

There is an error showing the following on the web application.

```
Cannot create ActiveX component.

[Exception: Cannot create ActiveX component.]
   Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.CreateObject(String ProgId, String ServerName) +469504
   frmbarcodeeval.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) +268
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +71
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +3178
```

This occurs when we transfer the web application to a new intranet webserver. Looking on its source code, it points to this code:

```
Dim R3 As Object
R3 = CreateObject("SAP.Functions") ' Error occurs here
```

I tried adding the reference object of SAP, which was stated [here](http://scn.sap.com/people/vikas.sreedharan/blog/2007/12/12/accessing-sap-functions-from-excel-using-visual-basic-applications), but it does not work. We also tried installing SAP GUI but it does not work too.

**##### UPDATE**

I found this [link](http://scn.sap.com/thread/2014873#10555145) which can solve my problem. However, I cannot change the target CPU to x86. It is a Web Site Project. I am currently trying my luck to convert it to a Web Application to make target platform show x86.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is a COM/DCOM object then make sure you have properly registered it on that server using RegSvr32.

[image]

**Edit**: If you need to run this as the Admin then you can simply create a batch file that includes the command and then select that batch file and "Run as Administrator". That could solve the problem else iot could be a 64-bit binary trying to be reg

Comment: This might mean you are trying to register a 32-bit on 64-bit. See if this article helps --> https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/1fd6b78a-b1b3-4190-aceb-91575cd7092a/cannot-register-mscomct2ocx-using-regsvr32?forum=w7itprogeneral

Comment: I have successfully registered the component but it doesn't solve the issue. It still produces the error.

Comment: Try to register it again now that it has been removed.

Comment: BTW, I am using a 64-bit Windows 7. Looking at the last link you gave, it shows that there are two regsrv32 on my OS. One from `SysWOW64` and `system32`. Which should I use from the two. PS: I used both but it shows the error again. My guess is, maybe there are other components needed aside from wdtfuncs.ocx but I can't trace it.

Comment: if it is DCOM then look for enableing com/dcom. This may help...https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771387.aspx

Comment: Doesn't work too.. I found out that aside from `wdtfuncs.ocx`, I need to register `wdtlog.ocx` and `librfc32.dll` but the error on creation of object does not solve the issue.

Comment: Do you have an option to allow activeX objects in the browser? Is it a windows app or a web app?

Comment: It is a web application.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the solution - but it's how I solved the problem. 
I just installed SAP GUI on the problem machine. The installation of SAP GUI took care of every component to be installed and registered. 
If you are running IIS based application then enabling 32-bit applications will help too. Go to IIS > Application Pool > Advanced Settings > General > Enable 32-bit Application. (Set it to 'True')

Building the application with 'Any CPU' is okay.